# Can't see the cursor after Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-20.04, cursor

If I boot Ubuntu, I can see my cursor. If I boot Windows 10 on my machine, I can't see the cursor. How can I fix that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Le9v.jpg)

Be aware that I use a stand mousepad with my laptop.

**EDIT**

I have a lenovo flex 5. How can I update the driver for the mousepad to solve that problem?

Comment: How is the mouse connected?  Does the port work after restarting? Did you try an updated driver?

Comment: @John I just use a standard mousepad with my laptop. The computer is brand new.

Comment: There should be a mousepad driver.  Try updating / reinstalling the driver

Comment: How can I do that? The driver doesn't need to be updated if it works with when I booted ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe try  a Bluetooth mouse just to see if that works in both systems.

Comment: *The driver doesn't need to be updated if it works with when I booted ubuntu* No, this is completely wrong. You don't understand that one OS has nothing to do with the other. You didn't undertand this when you posted this same question in AU and it has nothing to do with Ubuntu; you still don't understand now. That the touchpad works in Ubuntu merely says the hardware is fine. Why it doesn't work in Windows is indeed very likely a matter of drivers so please, before anything else, do as suggested and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @John I'm sure a much cheaper USB mouse will do as well. ;)

Comment: @John How can I update the driver?

Comment: Go to the manufacturer's Support site and look for the Mousepad driver.  That is how I get my Laptop drivers.

Comment: You may wish to re-think dual booting. That is much more complicated than driver updating. Maybe run the lesser used system in a virtual machine. That will work better.

Comment: @John I did not dual boot my laptop.

Comment: The Ubuntu comment was confusing. Try updating the driver and if Window is corrupted then trying rebuilding it with a Windows 10 Repair Install.